# Wireframe shader sometimes won't render parts depending on camera rotation

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl

I'm trying to make a stylized wireframe shader for a game using [this method](http://strattonbrazil.blogspot.com/2011/09/single-pass-wireframe-rendering_10.html), but it seems to be conflicting with my character controller.

Here's some images to better show what's going on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HGVr.jpg
Basically, as I look around, some lines will disappear and reappear. It might have something to do with culling but the face is still visible, so theoretically shouldn't all the vertices still be rendered?

It would also help if you knew of a better method for doing this as well. If it helps, I'm using OpenGL with c++, and my shader code is functionally the same as what I linked to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geometry shader wireframe not rendering correctly GLSL/OpenGL/C++](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136915/geometry-shader-wireframe-not-rendering-correctly-glsl-opengl-c)

Comment: If you look into the comments (last one) of the article, there is somebody describing your problem and providing the link above. Quote from the comment: "If you the geometry shader above, you will end up with incorrect distance values ... This is because the transformation from world to screen space (vec2 p0 = WIN_SCALE * gl_PositionIn[0].xy/gl_PositionIn[0].w;) is wrong. You need to multiply by HALF of the size of your viewport, because (0;0) is in the middle."

Comment: @wychmaster I've tried that and dividing WIN_SCALE by 2, or even changing it to other values of the same aspect ratio doesn't seem to affect anything. The lines render properly when they actually render, but sometimes they don't render at all.

Comment: Maybe there is an error in your code. Edit the code you think that is relevant into your question so that we can have a look at it.